# How to avoid the overhead of DummyNet pipes

Tags: pipe, freebsd, lan, emulation, testbed

I am working on a project where I would like to emulate latencies like nodes that are located in diffrent countries. To be more specific I want to emulate the PlanetLab system in a LAN using DummyNet. So that a node in the LAN to run multiple instances of my programme, so with 20 machines I would like to achieve having 200-1000 around the world.

What worries me is the overhead of DummyNet pipes. If I want 1000 of them in each of the machines, making them beforehand, it's going to be a great overhead because these machines are not running my program only (it's a test-bed used by multiple groups).

*It's going to be around 1000 pipes because I want each instance to communicate with all the others.

**Question #1**: Is it really a great overhead having around 1000 DummyNet pipes beforehand?

**Question #2**: Is there a way to create them somehow dynamically (open them when necessary) OR any other way to face this problem?

Thank you for your help in advance :)